# Edit Class Library code while running web application in debug

Tags: c#, asp.net

I was wondering if its possible to edit my C# Class Library code while my web application is running? ATM, my web application is referencing several class libraries, so while testing, I want to quickly change something and see how it affects the web app.

When I try to edit the code file, I get he message "Changes are not allowed while code is running. So I have to stop the entire solution, make the change, rebuild and rerun my web application. Is there a quicker way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the C# class library compiles down to a DLL and must be recompiled and processed through the CLR.  This is not like LiveReload with CSS and JavaScript.

Comment: Yeah thats what I thought. Thanks mate.